# I find a different definition of metapuzzle

Tags: discussion

Meta puzzle definition from wolfram alfa and youtube

[From youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBsb4A-NweI) 
[From wolfram alfa](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LogicMetapuzzleGenerator/)

So what meta-puzzle actually is ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those refer to "meta-logic puzzles", which we call [meta-knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-knowledge) and [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars).

A [metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzle) in the puzzle community is a puzzle that combines answers from other puzzles to get a final solution. For example, you might have this list of answers from solving seven puzzles:

**ARRANGE**
**CANCELLING**
**CROOKED**
**SCRABBLE**
**SEVENTEEN**
**TTYL**
**VACUUM**

You could notice that

> each of the answers has a double letter. Also, the double letters are all at unique positions in the word - **TTYL** has it at the beginning, **ARRANGE** has it after one letter, **CROOKED** has it after two...
>
>  You would then sort them by how many letters come before the double letter:
>  `-`**`TT`**`YL`
>  `-A`**`RR`**`ANGE`
>  `-CR`**`OO`**`KED`
>  `-VAC`**`UU`**`M`
>  `-SCRA`**`BB`**`LE`
>  `-CANCE`**`LL`**`ING`
>  `-SEVENT`**`EE`**`N`
>  The double letters now spell out TROUBLE, and that would be the answer to the metapuzzle.

Metapuzzles can be a lot more complicated than that, and sometimes they use something else too (like a diagram that you have to fill the puzzle answers into). This is the basic idea though - a puzzle *made out of* answers to other puzzles, where you have to figure out how to combine them.